# Unity Script is not running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am creating all new unity project and added Empty GameObject in to my first Scene, and also created and added script to that object, but when i'm trying to run my scene script dose not showing any output in my console window.
here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Start method called.");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Update method calling.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the GameObject this script is attached is being created when you run the scene?

Comment: yes i have already attached script to my game object, i've search a lot yo solve this issue also i was reinstalled my unity still its not working

Comment: You sure you added this script to that gameObject and that gameObject and this script both are active during runtime? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: here is the screenshot of my project : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c6d307f0d909e0df99f2956ad6396e2c20190820091443/8eead3/preview/c0d045a874bfd0ebc4d3d7a4080c2f9720190820091443

Comment: Are you trying to use built-in Unity's console or something like Terminal or CLT? If it's built-in console, please make a screenshot of it.

Comment: @vaskopatric that is quite weird. Try to attach this script in Main Camera and run? Also, show us the console, warnings/error messages etc.

Comment: I've already tried to attached script to main camera still i'm not getting single word outoput https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c3ae1d03969bbc404a6d3ca2dc81ebbb20190820092239/f825c3/preview/6db9592a125f05bc87b6d5ae9c302eed20190820092239

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on showing of another types of log messages ("Info" messages in your case).[image]

Comment: Simple yet effective ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that your button of the console output is enabled. Just try to click on the button.[Look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Onz.png)